# Angular JS Json data

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, json, model-view-controller

I am self educating myself in angular js.  For this i have created a project modelled after an actual project in my job

**All get operation work fine  but POST is giving me issue**

My controller.js

```
var ngapp = angular.module('ngWebApp', ['angularUtils.directives.dirPagination']);
ngapp.controller('ngIndexController', function ($scope, ngDashboardService) {
 $scope.exportData = function (selectedDataList) {

    var getData = ngDashboardService.AddReportAudit(selectedDataList)
    getData.then(function (result) {
            alert(result.data);
        }, function () {
            alert('Error in getting records');
        });        
    };
});
```

My service.js

```
angular.module('ngWebApp').service("ngDashboardService", function ($http) {
    this.AddReportAudit = function (dataList) {
        var response = $http({
            method: "POST",
            url: "/Home/AddReportAudit",
            data: {
            'dataList': JSON.stringify(dataList)
            }
        });
        return response;
    };
});
```

My code of JasonResult in HomeController

```
 public JsonResult AddReportAudit(List<ADTOWebSMARTT_SSOData> dataList)
 {
    if (dataList != null)
    {
        using (HRMSystemEntities contextObj = new HRMSystemEntities())
        {
            var itemList = dataList.Where(x => x.IsChecked == true).ToList();
            itemList.ForEach(a => a.DateChecked = DateTime.Now);
            contextObj.SaveChanges();
            return Json(new { success = true });
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return Json(new { success = false });
    }
}
```

The problem occurs here 
    public JsonResult AddReportAudit(List dataList)
For some reason the dataList on reaching AddReportAudit become empty i.e. list has zero element.  dataList  has 30 records in controller.js and service.js.

I am not sure why that is happening. is there a parsing that I am missing when json data comes from angular to c#

Comment: Did you try to put [FromBody]  in front of your list  parameter for AddReportAudit? Also, put contentType:'application/json' and dataType:'json' in your angular request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are actually sending an Object, so the data that reaches your public JsonResult AddReportAudit(....isAnObject), but you are expecting it to be a list. Just change your controller code to the snippet below, it should work.

```
angular.module('ngWebApp').service("ngDashboardService", 
    function($http) {
       this.AddReportAudit = function (dataList) {
          var response = $http({
             method: "POST",
             url: "/Home/AddReportAudit",
             data:JSON.stringify(dataList)
          });
       return response;
    };
});
```

Comment: u my friend are a genious

Answer (score 0):

Solution for angular 1. Place your web service url and change the json data format as per your need. It works.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Angular HTTP service</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>S No</th>
            <th>Source Name</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="res in result">
            <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
            <td>{{res.source_name}}</td>
        </tr>


    </table>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
        app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope, $http){
            $http.get("http://127.0.0.1:4000/all_source").then(function(res){
                //console.log(res.data.result);
                //console.log(res);
                $scope.result = res.data.result;
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Please read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors) meta question and make sure, that you don't include a picture next time, but the text itself.